# How do I use the Bluetooth module in the Arduino MKR Wifi 1010?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently trying to set up a program using the Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) module in the [Arduino MKR Wifi 1010.](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mkr-wifi-1010)
Currently though the only library that I can find is [CurieBLE for the Arduino/Genuino 101](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CurieBLE).

Are the correct libaries availiable in the IDE or are they somewhere else to be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ArduinoBLE library](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE) for Bluetooth LE support on the MKR 1010. The ArduinoBLE API is similar to CurieBLE but the implementation is different.